# Url not being called through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, url

I'm trying to send some data to my django view through ajax. For some reason, the url is not being called. It always alerts "Not found!".

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/AddToDb/",
type: "POST",
data: {"id":6,"quantity":3},
csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
success: function(){
     alert("Found!");
  // code to update DOM here
},
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
   alert("Not found!");
}
```

});

This is my url:

```
url(r'^AddToDb/$', 'Phase_2.views.AddToDb'),
```

And this is my view:

```
def AddToDb(request):
jdfsjfhs
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    JSONdata = request.POST['data']
    dict = json.JSONDecoder().decode('JSONdata')
    obj = ShoppingCart.objects.get(id=4)
    obj.quantity =  dict['quantity']
    obj.save()
return render(request,"HTML.html")
```

It's just a dummy call to check whether i'm able to send data to my view or not. I'm a newbie so i'm sure i'm making a stupid mistake somewhere. Please help!

P.S The "jdfsjfhs" in my view is just to check whether the view is being called or not. It's not being called.

Comment: Check **Network** tab of your chrome or firefox browser. It will show you complete absolute URL. Copy it and paste here.

Answer (score -1):

When making an ajax request. You need to send full url for instance localhost/AddToDb or www.example.com/AddToDb . You can check the final generated request from console section of either firefox or chrome. Hopefully that shall help.

Comment: Okay i did what you said. Now the alert message says "Found!" but it still does go into the view.

Comment: And when i try to go directly to the url "https://127.0.0.1:8000/AddToDb/" from my browser, i get the following error: 

**SSL connection error**:
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.

Answer (score -1):

use firebug to debug your javascript function. it will tell you whether the function is sending the correct response or not.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.